# Differences Between getBean(String var) and getBean(String var1, Class<T> var2) in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have came across two methods in spring framework when i try to learn it.

```
Object getBean(String var1) throws BeansException;

<T> T getBean(String var1, Class<T> var2) throws BeansException;
```

I did little performance test on those methods with that code:

```
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Customer customer = context.getBean("customerBean", Customer.class);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("NOT CASTED TIME: " + (endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Customer customer1 = (Customer) context.getBean("customerBean");
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("CASTED TIME: " + (endTime - startTime));
```

The output was:
NOT CASTED TIME: 17
CASTED TIME: 1

Also i have set the scope "prototype" for bean.If it was singleton the output going to be same for both of them.

What is the differences?

Comment: Testing just one time is not a sufficient performance test. Do some warm up, then test it multiple times, then see if the elapsed time is still that different. I think that the first takes "so long" because it firstly has to make the instance of the bean, while in the second case the bean is already instantiated

Comment: what is the real question? why they have different performance characterstics? or what is the difference in functionality?

Comment: performance characteristics i guess it is related to functionality @sodik

Comment: Did you read the javadoc for those methods?

Answer (score 1):

For the functional difference, you can refer the javadocs for those methods.
But for performance testing, I recreated the scenario and here is what I got 
 for

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Customer customer = context.getBean("customerBean", Customer.class);
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("NOT CASTED TIME: " + (endTime - startTime));

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Customer customer1 = (Customer) context.getBean("customerBean");
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The output was:
NOT CASTED TIME: 10 
CASTED TIME: 0

And If I reverse the order like this

```
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Customer customer1 = (Customer) context.getBean("customerBean");
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("CASTED TIME: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Customer customer = context.getBean("customerBean", Customer.class);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("NOT CASTED TIME: " + (endTime - startTime));
```

Then the output was:
CASTED TIME: 10 
NOT CASTED TIME: 0

and if you go on repeating the code further you will get the same value.
 **CONCLUSION: irrespective of the method, it will take more time only for the first time.**